# Using Google API URL in VueJS

Tags: api, google-maps, vue.js, axios

i have a URL like this

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=30.03049985444775,31.40335779637098&destination=30.185096658446447,31.520390957593914&language=ar&key=Key

when i try to use it in axios i get error

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=30.03049985444775,31.40335779637098&destination=30.185096658446447,31.520390957593914&language=ar&key=Key' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is answered here: [Google Maps API: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44336773/google-maps-api-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-reque)

You need to be using the [Google Maps JS API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial).

Comment: How to do it in vue, I just want to get response from this url

Comment: Actually the answer is there. You cannot do that. You need to use the GoogleMaps JS API